# What distance measure (e.g. Jaccard) to use when there are correlated observations?

Tags: correlation, distance-functions

I would like to use a simple distance measure (e.g. Jaccard) on a rather sparse set of 0/1 variables or probability densities, for which some of the observations are similar; this is due to repeated measurements or technical reasons. If I google for distance measures + correlated observations, not much came up.

I am looking to calculate distances between variables in a large matrix (9000x9000), so I am wondering if there is anything beyond mixed models that are more computationally efficient (hence Jaccard)?

Comment: for example  http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/mahalanobis.html

Comment: If some individuals (rows) are duplicated they are same, not similar, aren't they? Then if you know which. you could remove the duplicates.